# Using OutVariable Creates ArrayList

Tags: powershell

I'm sure there is a valid reason why this happens but I don't know what it is.  I have the following code

```
$Deleted = $Items[0].ParentNode.RemoveChild($Items[0])
Write-Output $Deleted
```

If I call this code using

```
Do-Something -OutVariable Test
```

I get the output on the screen and in the variable as expected, but the variable is an `ArraryList` with a single element that is of type `XmlElement`

If Instead I run

```
$Test = Do-Something
```

I don't get the output on the screen, as expected, and the returned output is a single object of type `XmlElement`

Why does `OutVariable` return an `ArrayList` rather than return the single item the function returns?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.2:

- **PowerShell unexpectedly does *not* unwrap a command's *single*-object output with

  `-OutVariable`**: That is, even if a command outputs only *one* object, that object is unexpectedly stored as an *array* (array list) in the target variable whose name is passed to the common parameter `-OutVariable` parameter (or its alias, `-ov`).
- Additionally, the **type of the value stored in the target variable is always `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`, an array *list***, which is **inconsistent** with capturing multi-object output in a variable by **regular assignment**, which results in **`System.Object[]`, a *regular* array**.

See [GitHub issue #3154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154).

Here's a **concise test** that demonstrates the problem:

```bash
$null = Get-Date -OutVariable ov; $ov.GetType().FullName
```

As of the versions listed above, this outputs:

```bash
System.Collections.ArrayList
```

even though the output is (conceptually) only a *single* `[datetime]` (`[System.DateTime]`) instance.

Contrast this with a regular assignment: `$v = Get-Date; $v.GetType().FullName` yields `System.DateTime`.

---

The **workaround** is to wrap the output-variable reference in the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) (**`$(...)`**), which gives you the same output as via the regular output (success) stream:

- a single-element collection is unwrapped (only outputs the element itself)
- a multi-element collection is returned as a `System.Object[]` array.

```bash
# Note the $(...) around $ov
PS> $null = Get-Date -OutVariable ov; $($ov).GetType().FullName
System.DateTime  # 1-element System.Collections.ArrayList unwrapped
```

Of course, you could also use `$ov[0]` if you only ever expect a single output object.

A demonstration that the workaround is effective with multi-element output too:

```bash
PS> $null = Get-ChildItem / -OutVariable ov; $($ov).GetType().FullName
System.Object[] # multi-element System.Collections.ArrayList converted to array
```

Comment: i think this got fixed in 5.1.14393.2969 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799474/how-to-redirect-output-from-command-to-variable

Comment: @Cataster: No, it hasn't: just try `$null = Get-Date -OutVariable ov; $ov.GetType().FullName`, and you'll see that even single-object output is still stored in a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instance.