# How to redirect output from command to variable?

Tags: powershell

How do i redirect output from this command to a variable?

```
Restore-ASDatabase -Server $Server -RestoreFile $File -Name $CINPUT -Security:$Choice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop
```

i tried this:

```
Restore-ASDatabase -Server $Server -RestoreFile $File -Name $CINPUT -Security:$Choice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop >$output

$output
```

didnt display anything. the command iteslf does actually output something. but i want to store this output to a variable

> The database restore operation completed successfully.

Comment: -outvariable (-ov) works. Restore-ASDatabase -Server $Server -RestoreFile $File -Name $CINPUT -Security:$Choice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop -ov $output . (note: my PSVersion                      5.1.14393.2969, other earlier versions reported -ov creates a collection https://stackoverflow.com/a/40666568/8397835)

Comment: You may not _notice_ that `-OutVariable` _always_ creates a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instance - even if only _one_ object is output by the command - but it definitely still happens - and is unlikely to change - see [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You save the output of a command as a variable like this:

```
$commandOutput = Restore-ASDatabase -Server $Server -RestoreFile $File -Name $CINPUT -Security:$Choice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop
```

Answer (score 5):

[D.J.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799637/45375) shows the most straightforward way to capture any command's (success) output in a variable - by direct assignment.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `>$output`

**`>`, the output redirection operator only supports redirecting to *files*** *specified by their name/path* (it also supports *suppressing* output with `>$null`) - you cannot use it to save output in a *variable*.

Therefore, the value of `$output` would be interpreted as the target file name/path; if variable `$output` was never created, this is tantamount to `> $null`, i.e., output *suppression*.

Also note that the files that `>` creates are invariably *plain-text* files that reflect the same output formatting that you would see in the console (terminal), and as such they are not suitable for *programmatic* processing.

---

By contrast, **the common `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) parameter you mention in a comment *does* allow you to capture a command's output objects in a *variable*, while not interfering with the command's output.**

That is, the command's output is still (also) written to the output stream, and if that output isn't consumed (by another command, a variable assignment, or a redirection), it still prints to the console.

E.g., `-OutVariable output` saves a cmdlet / advanced function's output in variable `$output` - **note the absence of `$` in the `-OutVariable` argument**:

```bash
PS> Get-Date -OutVariable output; $output

Thursday, June 27, 2019 10:17:07 PM  # direct Get-Date output
Thursday, June 27, 2019 10:17:07 PM  # output from $output
```

Therefore, `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) is useful:

- if you want to see a command's output in the console while also capturing that output in a variable for later analysis.
- if you want to capture an *intermediate* command's output inside a pipeline without interfering with the pipeline.

---

A **slight caveat** re `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) is that it:

- doesn't create regular PowerShell arrays (`[object[]]`), but instances of `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`.
- creates a - single-element - `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` even if the command outputs only a *single* object (as `Get-Date` does, for instance).

These surprising behaviors are discussed in [GitHub issue #3154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154).

However, given PowerShell's flexible collection handling and its [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) feature, the behaviors may not always be problematic in practice.