# List files with strings and then ALL files checked with powershell

Tags: string, powershell, file, search, pipeline

I want to search for all files, of .exe.config for certain strings.  I want to list the files with those strings and then list all of the files that were checked.  I can get it to find the files with the strings with:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -I *.exe.config -R| Select-String 'string1','string2'
```

My issue, I can't figure out how to get it to show all the .exe.config files that it checked (without searching the computer again).   I thought I could save the intial search results into a variable. Then run through that with a for loop, but I can't even get the right info into a variable.  I tried several variations of below, but $files is always empty.  Also, I'm not sold on this approach, so if anyone has a completely different method, that would be fine

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -I *.exe.config -R).Path
$files = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -I *.exe.config -R | select fullname)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#outvariable) to capture `Get-ChildItem`'s output in a variable of your choice, separately from what the pipeline overall outputs:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\ -Include *.exe.config -Recurse -OutVariable files |
  Select-String 'string1','string2'
```

Variable `$file` now contains all [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by `Get-ChildItem`; note how you must pass the variable name *without* the `$` sigil to `-OutVariable`.

A small caveat is that `-OutVariable`, as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0:

- collects multi-object output in a [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) instance rather than in a regular PowerShell array of type `[object[]]` (fixed-size array of [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object) instances).
- even collects *single*-object output that way (wrapped in a collection) - whereas direct pipeline output just emits the object *itself*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40666568/45375) for background information and a workaround.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @boblewis, and thanks for accepting and catching the typo - fixed now.